# Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all()

Tags: php, mysql

Meu código estava funcionando corretamente no localhost, porém quando subo para minha página Web, apareceu o seguinte erro:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method mysqli_result::fetch_all() in**

Esse é o código fonte:

```
function find($table = null, $id = null) {
$database = open_database();
$found = null;
if ($id) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE Codigo = " . $id;
    $result = $database->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $found = $result->fetch_assoc();
    }
} else {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE Status = true";
    $result = $database->query($sql);

    if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
        $found = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
    }
}

close_database($database);
return $found;
}
```

O erro está nessa linha:
**$found = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);**

Esse é o foreach que lista os dados, talvez ajude a encontrar o erro:

```
<?php if ($funcionarios) : ?>
<?php foreach ($funcionarios as $funcionario) : ?>
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $funcionario['NomeCompleto']; ?></td>
    <td><?php echo $funcionario['Porcentagem']; ?></td>
    <td class="actions text-right">
    <a href="Detalhes.php?Codigo=<?php echo $funcionario['Codigo']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open"></i> Visualizar</a>
        <a href="Editar.php?Codigo=<?php echo $funcionario['Codigo']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-warning"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i> Editar</a>
        <a href="Excluir.php?Codigo=<?php echo $funcionario['Codigo']; ?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i> Excluir</a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: vê se a extensão `msqli` está habilitado no PHP onde você hospedou o site.

Comment: Essa função precisa do mysql client instalado se não tiver troque o `fetch_all()` por `fetch()` e um while.

Comment: @rray, você consegue me ajudar a montar o while?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`mysql_fetch_all()`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php) precisa do MySQL native driver instalado, caso não tenha ele, troque por um `fetch()` combinando com `while`.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM " . $table . " WHERE Status = true";
$result = $database->query($sql);
$registros = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
   $registros[] = $row;
}

return $registros;
```

Comment: Muito obrigado mais uma vez por sempre me ajudar.